# Extracting the Y, Cb, Cr from a Mat in c++ and create a Mat with only the Y values

Tags: c++, opencv, extract, mat, luminance

I have two videos which I want to fuse. I plan to take the visible light video, capture frames, and convert the frames to YUV. Before fusing this with the IR video, I want to extract the Y component, put it in another image(variable) of type Mat of the same size and fuse that with the luminance of IR frame. After fusion, I want to put the Cb and Cr back to get the colors.

I saw this link: [Getting the Y and Cb , Cr values of a frame in openCV c++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13799025/2703464)

But I couldn't figure out how I can create my own matrices with this method of extracting Y, Cb and Cr.

Any ideas how I can do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

look at split() and [merge](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#merge)

```
Mat vis_img; // from cam

Mat ycrcb;
cvtColor( vis_img, ycrcb, CV_BGR2YCRCB ); // am i right assuming rgb input even ?

Mat channels[3];
split( ycrcb, channels );

// y is channels[0], cb is channels[1], cr, well...

// some operations on channels later..
// once you 'fused' your luminance channels into one, you can re-assemble the image
// from the channels:

Mat new_channels[3] = { lum_fused, channels[1], channels[2] };

Mat new_ycrcb;
merge( new_channels, new_ycrcb, 3 );
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm new to this so just asking a few points:
When you created a new Mat named channels[3], that is a 1D matrix right? 
Now it won't be of the same size as ycrcb and I wouldn't be able to fuse it with another frame ?
Does that make sense ?

Or am I supposed to somehow get this Y for every pixel and then create another matrix?

Comment: no, `Mat channels[3]` is an array of 3 empty Mats. they will get filled in the split() function. each of them will hold a 2d Mat the same size of the input img, with 1 color channel later

Comment: You can also use 'std::vector<cv::Mat> channels'. You can then acces the sperate channels by using channels.at(number).

Comment: @Nallath, is that a substitution for the split() function? I'd still need the initialisation : Mat channels[3] or am I completely wrong here?

Comment: You can use the vector instead of the cv::Mat channels[3] as input for the CV::split.

Comment: @berak, That works perfectly. I now have an image of type Mat which is a fusion of - Luminance of image_vis and Grayscale version of image_ir. 
I want to take the luminance of the NEW/FUSED image now. Is that possible with the same method?

Comment: @st1046, don#t know if i understand you right, you got 1 luminosity (from cam viaycrcb), another from grayscale(yes, that's luminosity/intensity, too). and now ? the main difference is, that they come from different cameras, right ? really, no idea, what you're up to.

Comment: @berak Apologies I didn't explain it quite right. Yes, I have 2 different videos, one from a visible light camera and the other from infra red. I am trying to capture frames from both videos, and fusing them together to get a better video. 
I plan to convert both frames from RGB to YUV (assuming both are RGB when I capture them), then use your method to extract the luminance,  fuse the luminance of both , and then merge the final (fused) image with the Cr and Cb of the visible light image to get colors!

Comment: ah, ok. so, 'fuse the luminance is the problem'. what would that be ? the average of both ? would be as simple as : `Mat lum = (lum_ir + lum_y) / 2;`

Comment: @berak So fusing the luminance is fine, I've done that, I'm having problems with merging the Cr and Cb of the visible light with the fused image/mat !

Comment: I was trying somethinglike this but my way of putting values into new_channels was wrong, this is awesome cheers!